# Table and td width issue

Tags: html, css, html-table

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE:

CSS

```
   .tablehead th{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
    color: #FFFFFF;  background-color:#000058;
    font-size: 13px; font-family:calibri!important;
    font-weight: 700;
    } 
    .tab_head th.tab_space {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.redtab_head th {
    /* Mozilla: */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C80000, #9F0101);
    /* Chrome, Safari:*/
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,
                left top, left bottom, from(#C80000), to(#9F0101));
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#pls-play { cursor:pointer; }

/*.tb1hide {
    table-layout:fixed!important;
     }
*/
.box  {
    text-overflow:clip!important;
    overflow:hidden!important; 
    white-space:nowrap!important; table-layout:fixed!important;
     -o-text-overflow: clip!important;  
      } 



*html .box { 
   width: expression( document.body.clientWidth > 124 ? "124px" : "auto" ); /* sets max-width for IE */
}
```

HTML

```
 <table width="94%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="tablehead" id="pls-batting">
                      <thead>
                        <tr class="tab_head" align="right"  >
                          <th width="44" align="center"><span style="text-transform:lowercase;">q te</span>.R </th>
                          <th width="212" align="left" class="tab_space">tester</th>
                          <th width="54" align="center">tes</th>
                          <th width="34" align="center"> tes</th>
                          <th width="34" align="center" >tes</th>
                          <th width="34" align="center">te</th>
                          <th width="34" align="center">tes</th>
                          <th width="44" align="center">tes</span>.L</th>
                          <th width="34" align="center"> tes</th>
                          <th width="34" align="center" >tes</th>
                          <th width="34" align="center">tes</th>
                          <th width="34" align="center">tes</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="44" align="left" ><span style="display:none;">11</span>
                            <select name="psvsr_select" class="psvsr_sel_class" id="psvsr_select111904" style="width:40px;" >
                              <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                              <option>codeup</option>
                              <option>codeup</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                              <option value="2">2</option>
                              <option value="3">3</option>
                              <option value="senddown">Send Down</option>
                            </select></td>
                          <td align="left" class="box tb1hide" style="max-width: 124px;">dfjbdsjbfhjb bdshfbdshbfhb jasbdfhbasdhjb
                            <input type="hidden" name="psb_playerId" value="/111904/" /></td>
                          <td width="54" align="left" valign="top" >OF</td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="r_hr1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="r_hr1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="r_hr1" onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_hr1',0,3,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_hr1',0,3,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="return selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="r_bnt1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="r_bnt1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="r_bnt1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_bnt1',0,4,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_bnt1',0,4,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="r_ph1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="r_ph1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="r_ph1" onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_ph1',0,5,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_ph1',0,5,'tbl1')" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="r_run1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="r_run1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="r_run1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_run11',0,6,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_run11',0,6,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td width="44" align="left" ><span style="display:none;">11</span>
                            <select name="psvsl_select" class="psvsl_sel_class" id="psvsl_select111904" style="width:40px;" >
                              <option value=""></option>
                              <option value="lineup" >Lineup</option>
                              <option value="bench" >Bench</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                              <option value="2">2</option>
                              <option value="senddown">Send Down</option>
                            </select></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="l_hr1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="l_hr1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="l_hr1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_hr1',0,8,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_hr1',0,8,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="l_bnt1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="l_bnt1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="l_bnt1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_bnt1',0,9,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_bnt1',0,9,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="l_ph1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="l_ph1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="l_ph1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_ph1',0,10,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_ph1',0,10,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="l_run1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="l_run1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="l_run1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_run1',0,11,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_run1',0,11,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="44" align="left" ><span style="display:none;">11</span>
                            <select name="psvsr_select" class="psvsr_sel_class" id="psvsr_select111904" style="width:40px;" >
                              <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                              <option>codeup</option>
                              <option>codeup</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                              <option value="2">2</option>
                              <option value="3">3</option>
                              <option value="senddown">Send Down</option>
                            </select></td>
                          <td align="left" class="box tb1hide" style="max-width: 124px;">dfjbdsjbfhjb bdshfbdshbfhb jasbdfhbasdhjb
                            <input type="hidden" name="psb_playerId" value="/111904/" /></td>
                          <td width="54" align="left" valign="top" >OF</td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="r_hr1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="r_hr1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="r_hr1" onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_hr1',0,3,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_hr1',0,3,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="return selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="r_bnt1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="r_bnt1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="r_bnt1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_bnt1',0,4,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_bnt1',0,4,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="r_ph1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="r_ph1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="r_ph1" onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_ph1',0,5,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_ph1',0,5,'tbl1')" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="r_run1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="r_run1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="r_run1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_run11',0,6,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'r_run11',0,6,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td width="44" align="left" ><span style="display:none;">11</span>
                            <select name="psvsl_select" class="psvsl_sel_class" id="psvsl_select111904" style="width:40px;" >
                              <option value=""></option>
                              <option value="lineup" >Lineup</option>
                              <option value="bench" >Bench</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                              <option value="2">2</option>
                              <option value="senddown">Send Down</option>
                            </select></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="l_hr1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="l_hr1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="l_hr1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_hr1',0,8,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_hr1',0,8,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="l_bnt1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="l_bnt1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="l_bnt1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_bnt1',0,9,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_bnt1',0,9,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="l_ph1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="l_ph1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="l_ph1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_ph1',0,10,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_ph1',0,10,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" ><span style="display:none;" id="l_run1_hid">3</span>
                            <input name="l_run1" type="text" class="txt_fid" id="l_run1"  onBlur="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_run1',0,11,'tbl1')" onKeyUp="return chk_txtval(this.value,'l_run1',0,11,'tbl1')" maxlength="1" value="3"  onfocus="selectText(this);" ></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you are trying to achieve, what you are observing, and what about it is different from what you expect? In its current form this is not a question (it is a statement).

Comment: I want to control the text length. So i used text-overflow:clip; and max-width. But it is not work in ie.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with the following:

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. You are right. If I use this css, my total table deign were misaligned.

Comment: Are you saying you're still having issues?  or that this fixed it for you?

Comment: Yes it is still having issues. While i use the above css, all the td width expanded.

Comment: I'll need to see the rest of the code to fix your issue as it's not related to what you have above.  Can you post a sample page?

Comment: Yeah sure. I will post in fiddle.

Comment: fiddle not working in my system. I was edit my existing post. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

How about stripping this down a bit to see if the issue is with the property in IE or something else.  Does the following work?

#### HTML:

```
<table class="tablehead" id="pls-batting">
<thead>
    <tr class="tab_head" id="pls-play">
        <th># vs.R</th><th class="tab_space">PLAYER</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="oddrow player-10-5544" id="111904">
        <td>11</td>
        <td class="box tb1hide" style="max-width: 124px;">Cameron, Mike (FLA)fdgdsgfdtertwet dgfs aesfaesrf</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

#### CSS:

```
.tablehead th{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
    color: #FFFFFF;  background-color:#000058;
    font-size: 13px; font-family:calibri!important;
    font-weight: 700;
} 

.tab_head th.tab_space {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.box  {
    text-overflow:clip!important;
    overflow:hidden!important; 
    white-space:nowrap!important; table-layout:fixed!important;
    -o-text-overflow: clip!important;
} 

*html .box { 
   width: expression( document.body.clientWidth > 124 ? "124px" : "auto" ); /* sets max-width for IE */
}
```

It's hard to determine in it's built-out state what's relevant and what isn't, with the inline styles, onmousehovers, etc.  One of these could be at fault, but best to start with the stuff that is supposed to be working to make sure it is.

My guess is that the expression isn't working, but that's just a guess.